# (x+a)(x+b) choices in Zp[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am confused about choices for $f(x)=(x+a)(x+b)$ in $Z_p[x]$.

If $a=b$, then $f(x)=(x+a)^2$. This means there are $p$ choices for $f(x)$.

But what if $a\neq b$?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Then you are choosing two elements from $Z_p$. How many two-element subsets has a $p$-element set?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you for the reply. Is p^2 right? There are p^2 choices for x^2+cx+d, but f(x) is only a subset (because it is reducible) of it which is impossible to have p^2 choices.

Comment: I didn't understand the last part of your comment. Why is it "impossible"? And what do you mean "$f(x) is only a subset"?

Comment: You are overcounting. The number of two element subsets (the order of selecting $a$ and $b$ is unimportant) is $\binom p 2=p(p-1)/2$. May be review basic combinatorics? And, correct, the rest are irreducible. This is one way of counting the number of irreducible quadratic polynomials.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for the reply! Could you please tell me why the number of two element subsets is p(p-1)/2?

Comment: @Krish Thanks for the reply! If f(x)=(x+a)(x+b), then f(x) is a reducible polynomial. For all g(x)=x^2+cx+d, there are reducible polynomials and irreducible polynomials. If there are p^2 choices for g(x), then choices for f(x) could not be p^2

Comment: [Binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Combinatorics_and_statistics).

Comment: Okay!!! Then it is merely choosing two elements from a set of $p$ elements: $p \choose 2$